# Does a charge moving in the direction of electric field produce EM wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation

I am a 12th grade student and our teacher told us that a accelerated charge particle produce EM wave .So a charge particle moving in the direction of electric field or a charge particle moving in a circular path in uniform magnetic field should also produce EM wave?

Comment: Yes, one nice way to interpret it is the created electromagnetic field will (net) oppose the existing field. Consider conservation of momentum or angular momentum. EM fields seemingly break this by being able to accelerate charges without there being other particles (at least locally) feeling a counter force. The answer is that the EM field itself carries momentum and one interpretation of the induced EM field is that it dampens the existing field so as to borrow its momentum to accelerate the charge.